# Python wsgi OSError: [Errno 10] No child process

Tags: python, linux, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a python wsgi script that is attempting to make a call to generate an openssl script.  Using `subprocess.check_call(args)`, the process throws an `OSError [Errno 10] no child processes`.

The owner of the opensll bin is `root:root`. Could this be the problem? Or does apache not allow  for child processes?

Using just the `subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` seems to work fine, I just want to wait and make sure the process finishes before moving on.

`communicate()` and `wait()` both fail with the same error.

Running it outside of wsgi the code works fine.

This is python 2.6 btw.

Answer (score 1):

1. `OSError [Errno 10] no child processes` can mean the program ran, but took too much memory and died.
2. Starting jobs within Apache is fine.  Running as root is a bit sketchy, but isn't that big of a deal.  Note that the 'root' account setup, like `PATH`, might be different from your account. This would explain why it runs from the shell but not from Apache.
3. In your program log the current directory. If the script requires a certain module in a certain location, then that would cause weird problems.  Also 'root' tends to not have "current directory" (ie: ".") on the sys.path.

Comment: Sub processes created from a web application running under mod_wsgi will not be started as root and would run as the normal Apache user unless the specific program which was run had the setuid sticky bit set on it. The openssl on my system at least does not have a setuid sticky bit.